# Prove that is a tautology without using truth table

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I can't find a proper formula to prove that
$$(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((r ∨ p) \rightarrow (r ∨ q)) $$
Is a tautology; considering it's almost exclusively made up of implications. Can somebody help me?

just I want to know how to simplify it.

I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUvUn.jpg).

Comment: Assume $p\to q$. Then assume $r\lor p$; in case 1 we have $r$, so we have $r\lor q$. In case 2 we have $p$, so we have $q$, so we have $r\lor q$.

Comment: OK, so no truth-tables ... but what *can* you use?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to rewrite in conjunctive normal form by replacing $A \implies B$ with $\lnot A \lor B$, pushing negation inward, and distributing $\lor$ over $\land$:

$(p \implies q) \implies ((r \lor p) \implies (r \lor q))$

$\lnot (\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot (r \lor p) \lor (r \lor q))$

$(p \land \lnot q) \lor ((\lnot r \land \lnot p) \lor (r \lor q))$

$(p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot r \land \lnot p) \lor r \lor q$

$(p \lor \lnot r \lor r \lor q) \land (p \lor \lnot p \lor r \lor q) \land 
(\lnot q \lor \lnot r \lor r \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot p \lor r \lor q)$

Now notice that each clause contains a pair $A \lor \lnot A$, yielding

$T \land T \land T \land T$, which reduces to $T$.

Comment: https://ibb.co/BCWhXY4 I tried this

Answer (score 1):

The given statement is false iff
$p\to q=p'\lor q=1\tag1$
$r\lor p=1\tag2$
$r\lor q=0\tag 3$
From $(3),$ $r=q=0.$ From $(2),$ $p=1.$ But then $p'\lor q=0$ contradicting $(1).$

Comment: actually you use truth table

Comment: I used truth tables of some smaller propositions not the main proposition.

Comment: I am supposed to use logical equivalence rules

Comment: @AliRammal I supposed it was done and I proposed alternative solution.

Comment: the solution is not complete

Comment: You mean the idea is correct but it is not explained well? I think it is complete. @AliRammal

Comment: This is the indirect method. Not a full truth-table method but perfectly complete. And the OP never specified in their post what was allowed, other than ‘not truth-table’

Comment: @Bram28 Wow. Thanks... I didnt claim so much as you praised but It will do for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming: $p\rightarrow q$
2. Disjunction introduction: $q \rightarrow (r \lor q)$
3. Transitive property of implication (from 1, 2): $p \rightarrow (r \lor q)$
4. Disjunction introduction: $r \rightarrow (r \lor q)$
5. Disjunction elimination (from 3,4): $(r \lor p) \rightarrow (r \lor q)$

Hence assuming 1 gives 5, i.e. $(p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((r \lor p) \rightarrow (r \lor q))$, as required

---

*Let $A$ be $p$, $B$ be $r$ and $C$ be $(r \lor q)$. Statement 5 relies on statements 3 and 4 which respectively are $A \rightarrow C$ and $B \rightarrow C$*, and thus indicates that $B$ or $A$ proves $C$,  i.e. $(B \lor A) \rightarrow C$